# React routing path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a application with path as such

```
/
/app/dashboard
/app/events
/app/events/add
/app/report
/app/report/sales
```

I have noticed many applications show the login page at the following path `/` once logged in they are redirected to the app (in my case the `/app` path).

I want the user to see the path as / instead `/app/dashboard` or `/app/reports`.

How can I do this ?

One possibility I thought of is to do something like this

```
<Route path="/",()=>{
   isUserLoggedIn ? return <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} : return <Route path="/" component="Login">>
}>
```

Please suggest if there is some better way to do this, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do:

```
<Route path="/" component={isUserLoggedIn ? Dashboard : Login}>
```